# Mac CMU Garbled in Font Book

Tags: mac, font-encodings, computer-modern

As you can see in the image, if I double click on "medium" under cmu sans serif a window opens up that looks like there's been a text encoding error.

I forget if my Computer Modern was installed by MacTex or if I installed it from SourceForge but if I download the SourceForge version and open the .ttf files they also appear garbled.

This is just something I happened to notice. My computer isn't producing garbled documents and the CMU fonts seem ok in Word. Is this bad?

[image]

Comment: All of my tex-related fonts seems good. http://i.imgur.com/gdYcyiv.png

Although I've seens this before but haven't been able to figure out why. Everywhere the font is used the result is just fine.

Comment: You might need to clear the font caches. I am not sure how to do this in current OS X and can't quite remember how to do it in earlier versions. (I'm sure it is under `/Library` and/or `~/Library` but I don't remember the details of what you would need to delete. Does FontBook have an option for clearing or rebuilding caches?

Comment: @cfr I found a command online to clear the font cache, didn't change anything.

Comment: I got the same "problem" when opening an example of the font. All CMU fonts seem to cause this, since I can't replicate the error with other fonts. http://i.imgur.com/x4D5VQq.png

Comment: In my case, this happens to many many fonts, not necessarily Computer Modern.